# Convert day number to date of this year in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

In my dataset, values are returned grouped by a daynumber (sql: datepart(day, xx)). In SSRS (2005), I want to convert this integer back to a date value. Eg 1 becomes 1/01/2010, 32 becomes 1/02/2010.  I've already looked into the date/time functions of SSRS but don't seem to find any function that does the trick. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: How do you know what year the day refers to?

Comment: As a fact, I don't know that's why I've changed the problem a bit. My query now returns numbers from 0 to 10 referring to the day, so 0 is today, 1 is tomorrow. I need to do this because of fixed columns in SSRS but in the header of the columns, I want to display the according date. This can be done doing a dateadd of this value with Today(). Thanks anyway, but I've already worked around my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dateadd function, to add the daynumber (minus 1) from your query (as a number of days) to the first of January of the relevant year - eg:

```
=DateAdd("d",Fields!DayNumber-1,DateValue("01-JAN-2010"))
```

Answer (score 0):

My query now returns numbers from 0 to 10 referring to the day, so 0 is today, 1 is tomorrow. I need to do this because of fixed columns in SSRS but in the header of the columns, I want to display the according date. This can be done doing a dateadd of this value with Today(). Thanks anyway, but I've already worked around my issue.